# SQL function? Required hours per month

Tags: sql, t-sql, function, calendar

Just a quick question,

Is there a function that calculates the required hours per month available in SQL?
If not a holiday counter?

I want to create a table in SQL which is a calendar that looks something like this:

```
Year    Month    Required_Hours
2011    1        *
2011    2        *
```

Where the function would calculate the * value

--EDIT--

Required hours is: 8 hours per day

Days that are not counted: Saturday and Sunday + Holidays.

Comment: how do you define "required hours"?

Comment: My short answer is no; an existing function doesn't exist because different countries, states observe different holidays and different companies observe different holidays as well.  Thus there is no standard; so no generic function, you have to write your own.

Comment: what for Required Hours?

Comment: You need to write your own calendar, or maybe try to get some database that implements one. Then, storing required hours wouldnt be sensible either. An aggregation function/group by will get you that live at no cost on this basis.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you could do something like this
SELECT 24 * DAYOFMONTH(LAST_DAY(CONCAT(Year,'-',Month,'-',1)))

It would return the days in a month times 24 which equals the number of hours in that particular month. Maybe there are some similar functions in TSQL?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: there's no built-in SQL function.

Long answer: this obviously depends on how many holidays there are during a particular month.  One way to handle this is to have a table that stores general holidays and subtract those from the total.  On top of that, you might need to take into account personal holidays / vacation days per employee, and that would be yet another table.  However, once you have those, it's not that bad: use [`DATEPART(weekday, *date*)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) to find out whether a date is a Saturday or Sunday